# Python android app crashes after PIL.Image.open()

Tags: android, python, python-imaging-library, buildozer

I'm developing an app with Python that reads images with Pillow. It works fine on Windows but it crashes when I am running it on Android tablet (the app is built with buildozer). It crashes when this line is called:

```
image = PIL.Image.open(filename)
```

I tried to log the error but I got nothing.

NB: the filename is correct and Pillow is in the requirements in the buildozer.spec file.

Someone could help me to understand ?

Thanks!

Comment: Post more code and log

Comment: We really couldn't help more if we don't have more specific information. How do you know for instance that it is this line that crashes it? You should really look for more logging information before we can start looking into a possible cause.